# Graphql/React-Apollo: React map function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, map-function

In the console I am seeing the following data. It appears I am not using the map function correctly:

```
{data: {action: [{action: "Changed", timestamp: 1499348050,…},…]}}
data:{action: [{action: "Changed", timestamp: 1499348050,…},…]}
action:[{action: "User Assist Changed", timestamp: 1499348050,…},…]
```

I am trying to graph the data using the following function but the screen is blank:

```
render() {
  console.log('graph nodes:', this.props.data)
  return (
    <svg width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height}>
      {Object.keys(this.props.data).map((data, index) => (
        <circle r={data.r} cx={data.x} cy={data.y} fill="red" key={index}/>
      ))}
    </svg>
  );
}//render
```

Comment: inside your map console.log(data) to ensure the data you want is in fact there. The snippet of JSON you provided seems to be missing the things you want to access in your map.

Comment: I want to map action.

Comment: Based on the JSON you have provided `{data.r} cx={data.x} cy={data.y}` data does not have the attributes you want. I suggest you console the `data` to ensure you actually have the keys you want.

Comment: `{variables: {…}, refetch: ƒ, fetchMore: ƒ, updateQuery: ƒ, startPolling: ƒ, …}
action: Array(1072)  
[0 … 99]--new line here---
0: {action: "Changed", timestamp: 1499348050000, object: Array(1), Second: Array(1), __typename: "action", …}`

Comment: I would STRONGLY suggest to only return the portion of data you need to the component and not the entirety of data returned from your query. This will help you properly target the information you are looking for. React components have no need for the rest of the methods.

Comment: @N6DYN what other properties does `data` and `action` include? don't write the `...` dots, but instead print all the object. use `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.data))` in your render and please add the complete result to the question so we can have a look. With what you have we can't really tell why it's rendering blank.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map over action, and not the keys of data.

```
{
  this.props.data.action.map((data, index) => (
    <circle r={data.r} cx={data.x} cy={data.y} fill="red" key={index}/>
  );
}
```

This is assuming those properties do exist inside of each action.

If you are looking to use the map over action, try running this line in the top of your render

```
this.props.data.action.map(item => console.log("this is an action: ", item));
```

That will show you the information in each action, so that you can then manipulate it the way you are expecting to do so.

Comment: What properties are you referring to?

Comment: I mean, the data.r, data.x, data.y information. Those must be properties on action for this to work, otherwise you have not shown us the appropriate information to answer the question

Comment: If you check the original question I posted what is in console.  Can you explain what r, x and y are?

Comment: It was in your code. In the <circle> tag. You said r={data.r}.

Comment: This is what data looks like: `{data: {action: [{action: "Changed", timestamp: 1499348050,…},…]}}`

Comment: So instead of data.r it should be {data.action}?

Comment: I made the following changes but still blank screen: `{Object.keys(this.props.data).map((data, index) =>(
     <circle r={data.action} cx={data.second} cy={data.obj} fill="red" key={index}/>
      ))}`